# Dynamic returned type of RTK query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

lets say we have this hook for all restAPI calls

```
fetchData: builder.query<any, string>({
      async queryFn(arg, _queryApi, _extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) {

        const result = await fetchWithBQ(arg);
        return result.data
          ? { data: result.data as any }
          : { error: result.error as unknown as FetchBaseQueryError };
      },
    }),
```

hence every API has different result type so we forced to put return type as ANY

```
fetchData: builder.query<**any**, string>
```

my question is how to define different return type for each api call

```
  const { data } = useFetchDataQuery(
    `example/me1`
  );

 const { data } = useFetchDataQuery(
    `example/me2`
  );
```

something like

```
 const { data } = useFetchDataQuery<DATA_TYPE_HERE>(
        `example/me1` as string
      );

const { data } = useFetchDataQuery<DATA_TYPE_HERE_2>(
        `example/me2` as string
      );
```

Comment: If you aren't really typing the slice, then I don't think there's much you can do. I don't believe RTKQ returns generic hooks. What if you just recast `data` in the component where you know the type because you know the endpoint? The alternative is to split your endpoints to the specific endpoints you are hitting and type the return value.

Comment: @DrewReese should I create slice for each API call , is it consider as a best practice ?, thanks in advanced

Comment: No, I'd say you only need one API slice per base query, e.g. `"example/*"` or `"example2/*`, basically for each backend server you need to hit, then you define as many endpoints as you need per each base query, e.g. `"/example/me1"` and `"/example/me2"`. Does this make sense?

Comment: In 99% of cases you would have one api, but many endpoints on it. This is a very weird usage to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that there's a property that acts as a "key" to tell you what type you really have, like the "type" property on actions tells you what leg of the switch to use (in old style reducers). I'd use [Discriminated unions](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-discriminated-union-intersection-types-typescript/), which is what is going on in old style reducers.

So say for example you have

```
type Me1 = {
   keyProp: 'me1';
   color: string;
}

type Me2 = {
    keyProp: 'me2';
    size: number;
}

type Us = Me1 | Me2;
```

Now you can type your endpoint query as `fetchData<Us, string>`, and then you will be able to switch on `keyProp` and confidently know if you'll have a color or a size based on whether that contained 'me1' or 'me2'. Now if the type is actually truly random, you can't type it, so good luck.